# Getting an error while using GCP Data Migration Service

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, database-migration, digital-ocean, google-cloud-sql

I am trying to move my database from a `Managed Digital Ocean MYSQL` database to `GCP Cloud SQL` and I thought I'd give the `Database Migration Service` a try.

> Note that I have already tried the One time mysql dump method and it
> works fine. I just wanted to try out the Continuous method to minimize down time.

Before even creating the job and running, I try to "`Test the job`" but I get the following error:
[image]

> zoho-tracker is the project name and destination-mysql-8 is the destination profile name. This is something else that confuses me, the button says "Go To Source" while the error string shows the destination profile name.

I have tried reading the docs as much as I could and I have checked the prerequisites too. Here are some points of information:

1. Source MYSQL version is **8.0.20** and destination value I am setting is **8**.
2. The GTID Mode value that I checked using `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'gtid_mode'` is found to be **ON**.
3. The `server_id` value is **2**(non zero).
4. All tables in the relevant DB are **innoDB**.
5. The user on the source has the following privileges: `SELECT, EXECUTE, RELOAD, SHOW VIEW, REPLICATION CLIENT, REPLICATION SLAVE`.
6. The user/pass/host combo has been verified many times and is correct.
7. The user was created with `'username'@'%'` string and not `'username'@'localhost'`.
8. The user was created with **mysql_native_password** plugin (*although I have tried different users which use the caching_sha2 plugin too*).
9. The connectivity method is IP allowlist and all connections while testing are allowed, so I don't think I need to add the destination IP to the allowlist.
10. The `version_comment` variable in the source has a value of '`Source Distribution`' not '`Maria DB`'.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: At the end of your question you mention "Maria DB". Which database are you using?

Comment: Source is MYSQL 8.0.20 and destination is GCP MYSQL v 8. I specifically mentioned "Not Maria DB" because in one of the documentation pages I saw that Maria DB is not supported yet.

Comment: This seems to be a issue with connection. How did you configure connectivity to source instance?

Comment: I have tried all options that came to my mind to treat it as a connection issue. Only thing I can't confirm is if Digital Ocean has some kind of thing built in to prevent this. I don't think that should be the case, but can't be sure.

Comment: Following this quick video with UI explanation, where exactly does your test block? I'm thinking about connectivity issues but i can't be sure  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wh7koygb1ZE&ab_channel=GoogleCloudPlatform

Comment: @MarcoMassetti the error shown in the question occurs after 3:41 in the walkthrough video.

Comment: Thanks, sorry but is a cleaner view now. Can you find something in the log? Otherwise i suggest you to do some connection test from an instance in GCE and see if you can reach your Digital Ocean db